Flask-Babel 4.0 Not Displaying Translations, Always Defaulting to English
I'm working on a Flask project and using Flask-Babel 4.0 for multilingual support. Although I have set up everything as per the documentation and there are no errors, the translations are not working — every page just defaults to English. I have already generated the .mo files, and get_locale() seems to be fetching the correct locale based on the URL segment.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
# Babel configuration in Flask
app.config['BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE'] = 'en'
app.config['BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES'] = './translations'

def get_locale():
    default_language = 'en'
    supported_languages = ['en', 'zh', 'es', 'fr']
    segments = request.path.split('/')

    if segments and segments[1] in supported_languages:
        g.locale = segments[1]
        return segments[1]
    g.locale = default_language
    return 'en'

babel = Babel(app)
babel.init_app(app, locale_selector=get_locale)

@main.route('/')
@main.route('/<lang_code>/')
def index(lang_code='en'):
    # Query some data, omitted for brevity
    return render_template('index.html')


And the HTML template starts like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ get_locale() }}">
<head>
    <!-- Head contents -->
</head>
<body>
    {{ _('Generate') }}
</body>
</html>


What I have checked so far:
The .mo files exist in the correct directories and are seemingly correct.
The get_locale() function retrieves the correct locale from URL segments.
Despite these configurations, every page still shows content in English only. Could there be something I'm missing in either the Flask-Babel setup or the way Flask handles these configurations?
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

This is my working setup:
babel = Babel(app, locale_selector=get_locale) #translations

def get_locale():
    if 'locale' in session:
        return session['locale']
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(['en', 'fr', 'sr'])


# List available locales
@app.route('/locales', methods=['GET'])
def get_locales():
    base_path = '/usr/local/panel/translations/'
    
    locales = []
    locales.append('en')

    # Iterate through all folders in the base path
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
        if 'LC_MESSAGES' in dirs and 'messages.po' in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, 'LC_MESSAGES')):
            locales.append(root[len(base_path):])

    # Return the list of folders as JSON
    return jsonify({'locales': locales})


# Change locale
@app.route('/change_locale/<locale>')
def change_locale(locale):
    if 'locale' in session:
        print(session['locale'])
    else:
        print("Locale not found in the session")
    session['locale'] = locale
    print(locale)

    if request.referrer:
        return redirect(request.referrer)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))


I check locales directories and display them on GET, then on POST update the locale in user browser an reload, on reload we check from session and display translation.
